# Invalid JSON message received

Tags: rest, api, post, fosrestbundle

I'm trying to POST into an API I have made, and I am testing it using Postman. I am getting back a 400 Bad Request error back as a response with the message `Invalid JSON message received`.

This is an example of the record being feedback to the user using GET.

```
{
    "id":3,
    "title":"Radio Etiquette Book",
    "summary":"This book provides advice on how to present a radio programme with flair.",
    "timestamp":"2016-12-22T18:18:20+0000",
    "author":{"id":1,...***},
    "reviews":
}
```

I presume the problem is with `author` because `author` contains sub fields, such as ID, username, password and sub classes called `entries` (books created by that author), and `reviews` (reviews written by that author).

How can I POST a new entry to avoid a 400 Bad Request error? I'm not sure which value it is, that I am posting incorrectly, but debating on whether it is actually author, and how it should be entered.

Comment: Can you show the API code? Or provide the API URL.

Comment: The "reviews" field could also be the problem, since there's no value for it in the given example

Comment: Which parts of the code you would like to see? The API url is local, i.e. `website.app/api/v1/books` so probably no use. I think I am posting to the right URL though.

Comment: Just tried reviews now, posted 1 into both author and reviews for a test and same error is returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a site like JSONLint to inspect whether or not the JSON you're trying to send is properly formatted. It should be able to show you the line of the error and why it might not match the JSON spec.

[link to JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: if that doesn't help, post us the error message you are getting, form the error.log. Error 400 can have a lot of causes.

Comment: Ok, great. So this has worked after using JSONLint `{"title": "Hello world", "book": "foo"}` (I wasn't passing an application/json header) but I only get a 201 in Postman. Should I be getting something more such as JSON response in the window?

Comment: The 201 response means that the request has been fulfilled and the resource has been created successfully.